In Flutter Focus node is not working for TextFormField when KeyboardType is number
I have a Flutter app with the following structure:

A ListView.builder that generates multiple Form widgets, each containing two TextFormField widgets.

An additional TextFormField outside the ListView.builder.


Each Form has its own GlobalKey, and each TextFormField has its own FocusNode. The TextFormField widgets have different keyboard types.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: provider.transactionList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final GlobalKey<FormState> cardFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    final FocusNode amountFocusNode = FocusNode();
    final FocusNode notesFocusNode = FocusNode();
    return Form(
      key: cardFormKey,
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Amount"),
              focusNode: amountFocusNode,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Notes"),
              focusNode: notesFocusNode,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);


I am able to manage the focus of each TextFormField properly, except when I set the keyboardType of the "Amount" TextFormField to TextInputType.number. In this case, the focus node stops working for the "Amount" field. The focus node works perfectly for other TextFormField widgets with keyboardType: TextInputType.text.
I've also tried using a single FocusNode object instead of two separate ones, but it did not resolve the issue.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or know how to fix this?
